# Installing AMDGPU 18.50 for Ubuntu 18.04 resulting in dependency issues

Tags: drivers, 18.04, dependencies, amdgpu

I downloaded the [appropriate driver from AMD's website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-64) and went to install it as I had the previous (18.40) driver. However, now I'm in a weird situation where it looks like there are unmet dependencies regardless of what I do and I don't believe the install is complete, even though `apt search amd` seems to list it as such. I am not at all experienced with managing dependencies (that's why there's a package manager right?) so I'm out of my element here. Can anyone give me any insight into what might be going on?

`# amdgpu-install` gives:

```
greg@desktop:~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-18.50-708488-ubuntu-18.04$ sudo ./amdgpu-install
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg                                                  
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg                                             
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                      
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                   
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                                               
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Fetched 247 kB in 1s (448 kB/s)                                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
amdgpu-pro-pin is already the newest version (18.50-708488).
Selected version '18.50-708488' (localhost [all]) for 'amdgpu-pro-pin'
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-lib (= 18.50-708488) but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: amdgpu-lib (= 18.50-708488) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libllvm7.0-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:7.0-708488)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 (= 1.15.0-708488)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 : Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488) but 1:18.1.0-676022 is to be installed
                                    Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers : Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa (= 1:18.2.0-708488) but 1:18.1.0-676022 is to be installed
                               Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1 but it is not going to be installed
 libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: libllvm7.0-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libxatracker2-amdgpu : Depends: libllvm7.0-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`# apt --fix-broken install` gives:

```
greg@desktop:~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-18.50-708488-ubuntu-18.04$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm6.0-amdgpu libllvm6.0-amdgpu:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-lib glamor-amdgpu gst-omx-amdgpu libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri libllvm7.0-amdgpu:i386 libllvm7.0-amdgpu
  libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 libwayland-amdgpu-egl1 mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers
  xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu
Suggested packages:
  libglide3:i386 libglide3
Recommended packages:
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 | libtxc-dxtn0:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 | libtxc-dxtn0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-lib libllvm7.0-amdgpu:i386 libllvm7.0-amdgpu libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 libwayland-amdgpu-egl1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  glamor-amdgpu gst-omx-amdgpu libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu
12 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 2 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/40.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 98.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libllvm7.0-amdgpu 1:7.0-708488 [11.9 MB]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libwayland-amdgpu-egl1 1.15.0-708488 [4,316 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libllvm7.0-amdgpu 1:7.0-708488 [13.4 MB]
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa 1:18.2.0-708488 [77.8 kB]
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa 1:18.2.0-708488 [75.4 kB]
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libwayland-amdgpu-egl1 1.15.0-708488 [4,344 B]
Get:7 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri 1:18.2.0-708488 [4,153 kB]
Get:8 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri 1:18.2.0-708488 [4,002 kB]
Get:9 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers 1:18.2.0-708488 [1,198 kB]
Get:10 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers 1:18.2.0-708488 [1,119 kB]
Get:11 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers 1:18.2.0-708488 [1,427 kB]
Get:12 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers 1:18.2.0-708488 [1,340 kB]
Get:13 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers 1:18.2.0-708488 [1,113 kB]
Get:14 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ glamor-amdgpu 1.19.0-708488 [69.7 kB]
Get:15 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu 1:18.1.99-708488 [56.3 kB]
Get:16 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ gst-omx-amdgpu 1.0.0.1-708488 [57.9 kB]
Get:17 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-lib 18.50-708488 [2,196 B]
(Reading database ... 206808 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libllvm7.0-amdgpu_7.0-708488_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm7.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:7.0-708488) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libllvm7.0-amdgpu_7.0-708488_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/BugpointPasses.so', which is also in package libllvm6.0-amdgpu:amd64 1:6.0-676022
Preparing to unpack .../libwayland-amdgpu-egl1_1.15.0-708488_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:amd64 (1.15.0-708488) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libwayland-amdgpu-egl1_1.15.0-708488_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0', which is also in package libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:amd64 1:18.1.0-676022
Preparing to unpack .../libllvm7.0-amdgpu_7.0-708488_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm7.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:7.0-708488) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libllvm7.0-amdgpu_7.0-708488_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/amdgpu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/BugpointPasses.so', which is also in package libllvm6.0-amdgpu:i386 1:6.0-676022
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libllvm7.0-amdgpu_7.0-708488_amd64.deb
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libwayland-amdgpu-egl1_1.15.0-708488_amd64.deb
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libllvm7.0-amdgpu_7.0-708488_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't remove, upgrade, or purge anything because as soon as apt finishes "reading state information" it tells me that I have unmet dependencies and stops there. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried contacting AMD support for help?  That is their pro driver.

Comment: Hopefully you have everything important backed-up to another PC or internet.
If you like fixing this sort of stuff then it is a great learning experience!  However if you haven't got time and patience, easiest way is to re-install ubuntu and just use the amdgpu included in the kernel with Mesa stable.

It looks like the following existing packages are preventing the new packages to finish installing:
-libllvm6.0-amdgpu:amd64 1:6.0-676022
-libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:amd64 1:18.1.0-676022.
Interestingly the last one above is newer than the one the amdgpu-pro installer is trying to install

Comment: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1_1.15.0-708488_amd64.deb  <  libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:amd64 1:18.1.0-676022   Not sure if it is apples and apples or apples and orange.

Comment: No I haven't contacted AMD support yet, but thanks for the suggestion. I'll be sure to follow up here if they help me solve it.

I can back everything up and reinstall, but i'd rather not have to go through all of that. And yea, I noticed that existing packages were causing a problem too, but I can't uninstall them because apt gives me the "fix your dependencies" message instead. 

Which would be better, though? I thought AMD's proprietary drivers would probably be the most optimal drivers for gaming, for example.

Comment: Radeon 18.50 or propriety driver hasn't been better than kernel-amdgpu + mesa for a while.  If I'm not mistaken a couple of years now.  The FOSS drivers perform better and are more stable.

Here's a benchmark of Radeon 18.50 vs linux 4.20.0+mesa 19 (go through the pages)
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=rx590-linux-drivers&num=2

Comment: Well that's...pretty sad and disappointing. Thanks for the info. If I can't figure out how to get rid of amdgpu altogether (because even the included amdgpu-uninstall script wont run on account of the dependencies) I'll probably reinstall. Thanks again!

Comment: Also games released for linux (like from Feral Interactive and Aspyr etc) as well Steam Proton games are almost always tested and certified against Kernel DRM + stable Mesa.

The "Pro" propriety drivers are more for non-gaming and compute tasks (datacentres and design studios) and for crypto coin mining.  



If you want the best hassle free gaming, go with the latest stable mainline kernel (currently 4.20.0).  You can use ukuu to get the kernel.  Make sure to choose stable not the rcs (release candidates).  Then after getting the latest stable kernel, get Padoka Stable Mesa.

Comment: Ukuu:  https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu

Padoka Stable Mesa:  https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa

Answer (score 2):

It took me several hours to figure out what combination of OS and Kernel along with proper steps works fine (i.e this may work on different combination but here is how I got it work - I thought it would be usefull to somebody out there).

install RX 570 Graphic card on ubuntu
in case of AMD installation errors:

### Working System:

Ubuntu:         20.04.1 LTS

Kernel Version: 5.4.0-54-generic

### Working Driver:

amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04

Steps to fix:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-*
sudo dpkg --remove libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri
sudo dpkg -P libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri
cd ~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04/
sudo amdgpu-uninstall 
sudo rm -rf /opt/amdgpu/
sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install
```

Answer (score 1):

You have what ever you need (packages) but your system is a 64 bit (amd64) but some of the AMD-GPU driver packages are 32 bit (i386). You should add i386 architecture to your package manager architectures, then update your package manager.

```
    sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
    sudo apt update
```

Also there is alternative methods to install these packages without add new architecture to your package manager. You can check them [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get 18.50 installed after upgrading to 18.04.1. I needed amdgpu to eliminate tearing on my htpc. However, 18.50 made things worse as a driver patch seemed to be needed for tearing to stay enabled with 18.50. So went back to 18.30. Though might try 18.40. Also upgraded kernel to 4.17.19-041719-generic in pursuit of fixing issue with 18.50 but still ended up going back to 18.30. Found errors with amdgpu drivers when I tried 4.19 or 4.20 kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Another try. Make sure you have all the repos enabled for your current installation. For instance I have 18.04.2 so I need bionic main, security, and updates. The first should be present. The latter two select in the software updater preferences. Check with

```
$ grep "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe multiverse main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe multiverse main restricted
```

Another Q and A suggested you need at least universe. Once you have the correct repos enabled the dependencies should resolve. The error does not show all that you need, and problems come from those outside the amdgpu installer. I traced my problem to non-amdgpu packages which required versions in updates, which I had disabled somewhere in my gyrations.