# AMD GPU Pro driver installation fails on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, amdgpu-pro

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
$ ./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy                            
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Packages [140 kB]
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [88.4 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 Packages [25.2 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main Translation-en [10.5 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1,424 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/universe amd64 Packages [13.5 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/universe Translation-en [6,392 B]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [660 B]
Fetched 332 kB in 1s (297 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '19.10-785425' (localhost [all]) for 'amdgpu-pro-pin'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-pro-pin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,988 B of archives.
After this operation, 29.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-pro-pin 19.10-785425 [5,988 B]
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pro-pin.
(Reading database ... 215126 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-pro-pin_19.10-785425_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pro-pin (19.10-785425) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pro-pin (19.10-785425) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.97-785425)
                Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.97-785425)
                Depends: libllvm7.1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:7.1-785425)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (= 1.15.0-785425)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (= 1.15.0-785425)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 (= 1.15.0-785425)
                Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-785425)
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 : Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (= 19.10-785425)
                    Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 19.10-785425)
                    Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 19.10-785425)
                    Depends: libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 19.10-785425)
                    Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (= 19.10-785425)
                    Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 19.10-785425)
 vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:3.3.1) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.8) but it is not installable
                          Depends: wsa-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
$ uname -r
5.0.0-13-lowlatency
```

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

Comment: Please look at my post at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147981/961950) ... It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Because of `amdgpu-pro` for 18.04. You can change `/etc/os-release` from `VERSION_ID="19.04"` to `18.04` before install. It is not the best but can be used.

Comment: This worked for me. Radeon RX580 "Red Devil" with Ryzen 5.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install 19.30-838629 on 19.04 (Kernel 5.0.0) with a patched script from Andrew Shark. You need to replace all version strings in his script with the version of the driver you want to install.
I run into problems with a later kernel version because some symbols were missing, so this will probably not work with at least kernel 5.3+.

[Script for installing AMD amdgpu driver on Ubuntu 19.04](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110795)