# Can't get AMD drivers to install

Tags: drivers, amdgpu

I am very new to linux and ubuntu. I'm trying to learn how all this works but frankly it's kind of hard.

I have 4 RX 580 AMD cards and I am trying to install drivers for the cards.

I am using ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

The driver version I have downloaded is

> amdgpu-install_21.40.1.40501-1_all.deb

I am following the amd instructions found [here](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

when i use the command

```
amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,opencl
```

this is what happens:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic is already the newest version (5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1).
linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic set to manually installed.
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic is already the newest version (5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1).
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-lib : Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you tried finding some related and solved questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107272/installing-amdgpu-18-50-for-ubuntu-18-04-resulting-in-dependency-issues) ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to install any additional drivers for that card. Is there some problem you were experiencing that made you think you do?  Also, it looks like your system might not be up-to-date. You should make sure your system is up-to-date before installing anything new.  In any case, installing software from files you downloaded from your web browser is probably the worst way to install software in Linux/Ubuntu, especially if you are "new to Linux".

Comment: He don't know about in-kernel drivers... nice point

Comment: Im using this particular system for mining. When I go to open my mining program it closes down because it says it can't find the cards (I believe can't find any opencl is what it says specifically, Ill confirm that when I get home).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get everything to work correctly following this. I also learned ALOT about differences between drivers in Windows and "drivers" in Linux.

https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/amdgpu-pro-20-45-amdgpu-dkms-fails-error-solution-for-ubuntu-20/td-p/458997

Comment: Link only answers are never good. What about later when this link is gone? If it has needed info in the link paste it in the answer.

Comment: Just making sure I understand what the expectation is. I should post the long list of step by step instructions to this forum?